# Fill TextBox by clicking a ListBox Item with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with ListBox and some textboxs. When I use below code and click any item in the ListBox, It's fill the textbox with List Index Number Instead of the Item Name.

**It's fills**

> 0 to textbox when I click on first item value (Boulder) from listbox.
>
> 1 to textbox when I click on second item value (RBM) from listbox.
>
> 2 to textbox when I click on third item value (Sand) from listbox.

and so on.

Note: Boulder, RBM, Sand are filled in listbox.

> **Required:**
> When I click on Boulder then textbox must be fill with text boulder instead of 0.

> When I click on RBM then textbox must be fill with text RBM instead of
> 1.
>
> When I click on Sand then textbox must be fill with text Sand instead
> of 2.

```
Private Sub lbox_Word_Change()
    TextItemName.Value = Me.lbox_Word.ListIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using ```Value``` instead of ```ListIndex``` and tell me if it works.

Comment: OMG, Perfect Solution. Thank You Very Much Mr. @Vincent

Comment: @PrabhatVishwas `TextItemName.Value = lbox_Word.List(lbox_Word.ListIndex, 0)` returns the first (and apparently only column, so column index 0); to avoid errors check before if there exists any actual row selection: `If lbox_Word.ListIndex > -1 Then` ... `End If` :-)

Answer (score 1):

A different and useful way (codes to populate text boxes (TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3 etc.) based on the selected listbox item) :

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
For a = 0 To 11
Controls("textbox" & a + 1) = ListBox1.column(a)
Next
...
```

[image]

[Tutorial source](https://eksi30.com/the-updated-excel-userform/)

Comment: Hi. Do you happen to have a copy of the file or a new source? The source seems to be down.